# Return top 5 records of a table in a dataset

Tags: vb.net, select, dataset

I want to return the top 5 records of a table in a dataset for  datagrid view.  The following does not work.

```
DataGridView.DataSource = DS.Tables("TABLENAME").Select("SELECT TOP 5")
```

Any suggestions?

Using Visual Studio 2008 - VB.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dataset is already populated, you can use LINQ to take the first 5 rows from a table. (*The more efficient method would be to handle this at the database, however*.)

```
Dim rows = DS.Tables("Foo").Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().Take(5)
```

Comment: Any good sources for LINQ? Like I said I am using an access database for the back-end data store so if LINQ is preferred method I should learn.

Comment: LINQ is *a* method, not always the preferred method, but it's great for simplification of code. I'm a C# coder for the most part, so I would point you to Jon Skeet's "C# in Depth" book. Absent that, MSDN is always reliable.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the TOP clause. THis assume you are using SQL Server.

ie `Select top 5 * from SomeTable`

If you are using MySQL there is the limit [clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

If you are using Oracle lookup ROWNUM

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or greater, you could use the ROW_NUMBER() function to number the rows, then use:

```
DS.Tables("TABLENAME").Select("row_number <= 5")
```

Answer (score 0):

Select doesn't work like that, take a look at the [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx).

What you want to do is create a View with your table, sort it and take the first five rows.

```
DataView view = DS.Tables[0];
view.Sort = "myColumn";
//Take first or last 5 rows.
```

Or of course just use a "SELECT TOP 5 x from mytable" and insert that into your datatable.